# Google Drive Capabilities Differences

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I'm trying to move files to different places with Google Drive API. Some files in Google Drive are unmovable, and I saw some variables in the `capabilities` section of the file JSON that describes whether the file can be moved, copied, etc. There are two variables that I'm confused about. One is `capabilities.canMoveItemOutOfDrive`, the other is `capabilities.canMoveItemWithinDrive`. I tested a file in my Drive and made it unmovable, but `capabilities.canMoveItemWithinDrive` is `true` while `capabilities.canMoveItemOutOfDrive` is `false`. The explanation provided by Google seems as if the `capabilities.canMoveItemWithinDrive` should be `false`. Can someone explain how to use these two variables? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capabilities are essentially a set of actions a user can take on a certain file from Drive.

As for the two capabilities you mentioned:

- `canMoveItemOutOfDrive`

> Whether the current user can move this item outside of this drive by changing its parent.
>
> **Note** that a request to change the parent of the item may still fail depending on the new parent that is being added.

- `canMoveItemWithinDrive`

> Whether the current user can move this item within this drive.
>
> **Note** that a request to change the parent of the item may still fail depending on the new parent that is being added and the parent that is being removed.

Therefore, if the `capabilities.canMoveItemWithinDrive` is `true` and `capabilities.canMoveItemOutOfDrive` is `false`, it means that your file can be moved only inside the drive.

However, if you check the `Files` resource documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource), you can see that both of these capabilities are **not writable**.

#### Reference

- [Drive API v3 Files resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource).